# ASP NET Web API google authentication issue HTTP 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth, google-plus

I am trying to setup a social login for my site.

Here is what I did:

1. I created credentials on google and have both ClientID and Secret
2. In default MVC app, in `App_Start Startup.Auth.cs` I uncommented
   app.UseGoogleAuthentication()* method, so it looks like this:

   [image]
3. Build solution!
4. Made sure authorized JavaScript origins and Redirect url are correct. And other things that are needed on console.cloud.google.com are done. Including activation of Google+ API

Eventually Google authentication button should appear in *_ExternalLoginsListPartial* partial view. But as I can see I have 0 login providers still. And not sure why, and what can I do about it?

```
var loginProviders = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes();
//loginProviders.Count() here returns 0
```

[image]

Tried researching, but most are saying that you forgot to build, or restart the server. Tried that but nothing changed.

As last resort, I tried following a tutorial https://youtu.be/WsRyvWvo4EI?t=9m47s
I did everything as shown there, I should be able to reach *api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true* url, and receive callback URL from Google.

But I got stuck with same HTTP404 error at 9:50

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question, everything turns out to be fine.
All I had to do was just to give it some time.
After couple of hours, Google provider appeared on the page.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers - if met with 404 in this case, another possibility is an active filtering rule against query strings in IIS. One of the commonly copy-pasted rules aiming to block SQL injection requests scans the query string for `open` (to catch `OPEN cursor`). Your OAuth request probably contains this word in the scopes section (data you want to pull from the Google profile)

1. IIS -> Request Filtering
2. Switch to the tab "Rules"
3. Inspect and remove any suspicious active filters there